# Div is coverd by another and z-index does not work

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm using Easy-UI layout, the blue part is the "north" layout to show nav, and down that is the layout part of "center".

But the pulldown div is coverd by "center" layout panel when mouse move-on.

I set z-index into pulldown div, but it doesn't work. How can I fix is?

```css
.hd-main .has-pulldown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  *z-index: 10000
}
.hd-main .pulldown {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  display: none;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0
}
.hd-main .pulldown .arrow {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
  _margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #F6F6F9 transparent;
  _filter: chroma(color=tomato);
  _border-color: tomato tomato #F6F6F9 tomato;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2
}
.hd-main .pulldown .content {
  background: #F6F6F9;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: rgb(175, 175, 175) 1px solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
.hd-main .pulldown-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0)
}
.hd-main .navs .def-nav,
.hd-main .navs .pulldown-nav,
.hd-main .navs .separate {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 48px;
  font: 18px/30px"Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft JhengHei";
  color: #d8d8d8;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 48px
}
.hd-main .navs .pulldown-nav {
  position: relative
}
.hd-main .navs .pulldown-nav em {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 69px;
  top: 18px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 0;
  background-position: -89px -45px
}
.hd-main .navs .pulldown-nav:hover .f-icon,
.hd-main .navs .pulldown-nav:active .f-icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 11px;
  top: 18px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 0;
  background-position: -89px -55px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="info-i user-name has-pulldown">
    <em class="f-icon pull-arrow"></em>
    <span class="name top-username">David</span>
    <div class="pulldown user-info">
      <em class="arrow"></em>
      <div class="content">
        <span class="li"><a href="">aa</a></span>
        <span class="li"><a href="">bb</a></span>
        <span class="li"><a href="">cc</a></span>
        <span class="li"><a href="">dd</a></span>
        <span class="separate-li no-height"></span>
        <span class="li"><a href="javascript:;" id="signout">Log Out</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Provide us with the code that you have tried and tell us what it doesn't do that you want it to. Show us your effort and only then can we help you.

Comment: Sorry. Code provided now.

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the problem. Please, try to provide bare bones code that actually reproduces your exact problem so we can help you further.